# Styling react-router-dom Link using styled-components getting warning when passing props

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, styled-components

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const LS = {};

LS.NavFixedItem_LINK = styled(Link)`

  display: flex;
  justify-content: ${props => props.tempLeftProp ? 'flex-start' : 'center'};
  align-items: center;
`;

function NavFixedItem(props) {
  return(
    <LS.NavFixedItem_LINK to={props.link} tempLeftProp={props.toLeft}>
      {props.name}
    </LS.NavFixedItem_LINK>
  );
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> **Warning:** React does not recognize the `tempLeftProp` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `templeftprop` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

I pass props to my styled-components all the time. I don't know if the problem is that I'm styling a component `Link` instead of a regular HTML element.

**QUESTION**

Why am I getting this error? Is it safe to just ignore it?

PS: The styles are being applied as intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally, React Router's `Link` passes all the its props to an `<a>` DOM element. Except the ones used by `Link`, like `to`. So the styles work because the props are interpreted by Styled Components, but then the same prop is passed again to the inner `<a>`, which triggers the (harmless) error message.

You could try having a wrapper with nested styles, like this:

```
LS.NavFixedItem_LINK = styled.div`
  a {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: ${props => props.tempLeftProp ? 'flex-start' : 'center'};
    align-items: center;
  }
`;

function NavFixedItem(props) {
  return(
    <LS.NavFixedItem_LINK tempLeftProp={props.toLeft}>
      <Link to={props.link}>
        {props.name}
      </Link>
    </LS.NavFixedItem_LINK>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 19):

### Use transient props

With the release 5.1.0 you can use [transient props](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props). This way you do not need an extra wrapper i.e. unnecessary code is reduced:

> Transient props are a new pattern to pass props that are explicitly consumed only by styled components and are not meant to be passed down to deeper component layers. Here's how you use them:

```
const Comp = styled.div`
  color: ${props => props.$fg || 'black'};
`;

render(<Comp $fg="red">I'm red!</Comp>);
```

> Note the dollar sign ($) prefix on the prop; this marks it as transient and styled-components knows not to add it to the rendered DOM element or pass it further down the component hierarchy.

### The new answer should be:

styled component:

```
LS.NavFixedItem_LINK = styled(Link)`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: ${props => props.$tempLeftProp ? 'flex-start' : 'center'}; // '$' added
  align-items: center;
`;
```

parent component:

```
function NavFixedItem(props) {
  return(
    <LS.NavFixedItem_LINK 
      to={props.link} 
      $tempLeftProp={props.toLeft} // '$' signals the transient prop
    >
      {props.name}
    </LS.NavFixedItem_LINK>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is for the users finding best solution with version 5.x 

Comment: Typescript throws an error if you use `to` instead of `href` in the props.

Answer (score 3):

another thing you could try the "to" prop on a react Link tag can take two different values a string or an object.

1. If it's a string, it represents the absolute path to link to, e.g. `/users/123` (relative paths are not supported).
2. If it's an object, it can have four keys:

   - **pathname**: A string representing the path to link to.
   - **query**: An object of `key:value` pairs to be stringified.
   - **hash**: A hash to put in the URL, e.g. `#a-hash`.
   - **state**: State to persist to the location.

your above code can be represented as:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const LS = {};

LS.NavFixedItem_LINK = styled(Link)`

  display: flex;
  justify-content: ${props => props.to.state.tempLeftProp ? 'flex-start' : 'center'};
  align-items: center;
`;

function NavFixedItem(props) {
  return(
    <LS.NavFixedItem_LINK to={{ pathname: props.link, state: {tempLeftProp: props.toLeft} }}>
      {props.name}
    </LS.NavFixedItem_LINK>
  );
}
```

Comment: Best Answer EZ PZ LEMON SQUEEEEZY