# (React) I have two buttons on my main page but can only style one

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, button, styling

I have two buttons on my main pages.

Button one is for scrolling to elements on the main page.

Button two is for linking to other pages on my website.

Button 1 is from react-scroll while Button 2 is from react-router-dom

Currently button 1 scrolls properly and displays styling correctly.
However button 2 links to other pages but does not display any styling and displays the property of "navToPage" rather than the value of "buttonLabel".

How can I correct this so that both buttons have styling and fuctionality?

Here is the code from Data.js that feeds into index.js

```
export const homeObjOne = {
  id: "about",
  lightBg: false,
  lightText: true,
  lightTextDesc: true,
  topLine: "Freeman Ltd",
  headline: "Professional & Affordable Services",
  description:
    "We enjoy helping our clients by utilizing over 20 years of experience.",
  buttonLabel: "Get started",
  imgStart: false,
  img: require("../../images/scales.jpg"),
  alt: "North West",
  dark: true,
  primary: true,
  darkText: false,
  navToPage: "services",
};

export const homeObjTwo = {
  id: "services",
  lightBg: true,
  lightText: false,
  lightTextDesc: false,
  topLine: "FAQ",
  headline: "We are here to help!",
  description:
    "Have Questions? We have answers.",
  buttonLabel: "Learn More!",
  imgStart: true,
  img: require("../../images/faq.jpg"),
  alt: "FAQ",
  dark: false,
  primary: false,
  darkText: true,
  navToPage: "/faq",
};
```

Here is index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "../ButtonElements";
import { PageButton } from "../ButtonPageElements";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import {
  InfoContainer,
  InfoWrapper,
  InfoRow,
  Column1,
  Column2,
  TextWrapper,
  TopLine,
  Heading,
  Subtitle,
  BtnWrap,
  ImgWrap,
  Img,
} from "./infoElements";

const InfoSection = ({
  lightBg,
  id,
  imgStart,
  topLine,
  lightText,
  headline,
  darkText,
  description,
  buttonLabel,
  img,
  alt,
  primary,
  dark,
  dark2,
  navToPage,
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <InfoContainer lightBg={lightBg} id={id}>
        <InfoWrapper>
          <InfoRow imgStart={imgStart}>
            <Column1>
              <TextWrapper>
                <TopLine>{topLine}</TopLine>
                <Heading lightText={lightText}>{headline}</Heading>
                <Subtitle darkText={darkText}>{description}</Subtitle>
                <BtnWrap>
                  {navToPage && navToPage.startsWith("/") ? (
                    //if it is linked to another page use router link
                    <Link to={navToPage} style={{}}>
                      {navToPage}
                    </Link>
                  ) : (
                    //else use the smart link component
                    <Button
                      to={navToPage}
                      smooth={true}
                      duration={500}
                      spy={true}
                      exact="true"
                      offset={-80}
                      primary={primary ? 1 : 0}
                      dark={dark ? 1 : 0}
                      dark2={dark2 ? 1 : 0}
                    >
                      {buttonLabel}
                    </Button>
                  )}
                </BtnWrap>
              </TextWrapper>
            </Column1>
            <Column2>
              <ImgWrap>
                <Img src={img} alt={alt} />
              </ImgWrap>
            </Column2>
          </InfoRow>
        </InfoWrapper>
      </InfoContainer>
    </>
  );
};

export default InfoSection;
```

Here is the code for ButtonElements.js

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Link } from "react-scroll";

export const Button = styled(Link)`
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: ${({ primary }) => (primary ? "#ca1f27" : "#010606")};
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: ${({ big }) => (big ? "14px 48px" : "12px 30px")};
  color: ${({ dark }) => (dark ? "#010606" : "#fff")};
  font-size: ${({ fontBig }) => (fontBig ? "20px" : "16px")};
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;

  &:hover {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background: ${({ primary }) => (primary ? "#fff" : "#ca1f27")};
  }
`;
```

Here is the code for ButtonPageElements.js

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export const PageButton = styled(Link)`
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: ${({ primary }) => (primary ? "#ca1f27" : "#010606")};
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: ${({ big }) => (big ? "14px 48px" : "12px 30px")};
  color: ${({ dark }) => (dark ? "#010606" : "#fff")};
  font-size: ${({ fontBig }) => (fontBig ? "20px" : "16px")};
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;

  &:hover {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background: ${({ primary }) => (primary ? "#fff" : "#ca1f27")};
  }
`;
```

Comment: `react-router-dom Link ` is basically an `<a>` tag you should check that you don't have other styles on `a` that overrides. Alternatively you could try to use the same tag of `react-scroll` and navigate through `useNavigate` onClick.

Comment: @CesarePolonara could you help me implement the navigation solution where I have functionality and styling? I am not sure how to procede

Comment: Start from doing an inspect on the Link element that doesn't wtyle and compare it with the other element, and you will see what are the CSS properties that are overridden.

Comment: @CesarePolonara ok! The working button displays as < exact="true" primary="1" dark="1" dark2="0" class="sc-bczRLJ fmoxXi active"> Get Started</a>

while the button with no styling shows as <a href="/faq">/faq</a>

Now that I know that what can I do next to fix it?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58094415/styling-react-router-dom-link-using-styled-components-getting-warning-when-passi

Comment: @CesarePolonara Sorry could you explain more on that?